# Why is the Date & Time Data Type Menu Disabled in Google Data Studio?

Tags: datetime, looker-studio

After connecting a data set to Google Data Studio I tried to update types of field of data source and notice that several options of date & time data type is disabled:

[image: data_source_date_text]

I couldn't find any method to enable it.

This is the Excel (CSV) data set used (sample [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B8h01agSyOirDlptglKpCmmM_Bep8L6YOKjegAkIrfc/edit?usp=sharing) data):

| Date | Shirt | Pants | Other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/1954 | 37 | 18 | 38 |
| 1/2/1955 | 34 | 25 | 14 |
| 1/3/1956 | 37 | 12 | 10 |
| 1/3/1957 | 38 | 20 | 23 |
| 1/4/1958 | 37 | 19 | 18 |
| 1/5/1959 | 33 | 30 | 37 |
| 1/6/1960 | 13 | 36 | 10 |
| 1/6/1961 | 15 | 29 | 29 |
| 1/7/1962 | 32 | 14 | 12 |
| 1/8/1963 | 21 | 36 | 33 |
| 1/9/1964 | 15 | 12 | 15 |
| 1/9/1965 | 11 | 24 | 13 |
| 1/10/1966 | 29 | 15 | 11 |
| 1/11/1967 | 31 | 30 | 20 |
| 1/12/1968 | 14 | 12 | 18 |
| 1/12/1969 | 37 | 13 | 14 |
| 1/13/1970 | 40 | 34 | 25 |
| 1/14/1971 | 36 | 17 | 35 |
| 1/15/1972 | 17 | 36 | 39 |
| 1/15/1973 | 29 | 29 | 34 |
| 1/16/1974 | 30 | 39 | 33 |

This is how Google Data Studio shows the relevant data:

[image: data_studio_output]

[Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/c6e659d6-e9ce-4808-a03b-af37785a7ade) report

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Date` field is recognised as a text [data type](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9514333) ("*Zero or more letters, numbers, characters, or symbols*"), thus the [`PARSE_DATE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9739156) function ("*Converts text to a date*") can be used to create a `Date` field that is recognised by Google Data Studio, in the [date](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9514333?hl=en#:%7E:text=A1B2C3-,Date%20%26%20Time,-An%20actual%20calendar), data type (*"An actual calendar date, a calendar date with time, or an abstract date or time index. This will be formatted according to the locale"*):

```
PARSE_DATE("%m/%d/%Y", Date)
```

The [calculated field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) above uses the [format elements](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/format-elements) `%m` ("*month as a decimal number (01-12)*"), `%d` ("*day of the month as a decimal number (01-31)*") and `%Y` ("*year with century as a decimal number*"), with the separator `/` between each of the elements, thus `%m/%d/%Y` parses `1/16/1974`.

Publicly editable [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/adc86311-ea81-4b95-ac34-080881d87b78) report (embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15Dx4jD8kZq774-dx1mcJSeDAQ2vQn3c9yCj4eaJ2T9U/edit?usp=sharing) data source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image: gif]